# Adding jar files to codenameone in NetBeans

Tags: java, android, mobile, jar, codenameone

I have an Android POS device that's equipped with a fingerprint scanner. They have a .jar library which is meant to help develop Android apps to access the fingerprint component in the device. I included the jar file in the lib folder of the NetBeans codenameone project and also in the native/android directory.

But when I run the application on the device after building on the build server, the application throws a NoClassDefFoundError. But the class is in the jar file.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to treat it like a native interface, which is actually pretty easy. You just create an interface with all of the method signatures you need, right click on it, and select generate native. Then in the native sub folder there will be an Android directory. You can drop the jar file in there and in the stub file that ends with "impl", you implement the interface methods to call the methods in the jar.

The downside of that is that the auto-code completion won't work. Since you're using Netbeans, if you do the above you should then be able to compile it into a CN1LIB. That can be then placed in your libraries and the code completion will work.

Check the developers guide in the Advanced Topics Under The Hood section, and there's a tutorial video also.

Comment: Yep, here's the developer guide link: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html

Comment: can i create a cn1lib that depends on the jar file. so that i can then add the cn1lib in lib folder of my project. if i do this way will the classes in jar file be available for me to consume in my own project?

Comment: All the classes that you include in the interface and invoke in your "impl" should be available with the cn1lib.

Comment: @James H : are you saying i should create a cn1lib and inside create the native interface thing along with my jar?

Comment: Please how can i add a jar dependency to a cn1lib?

Comment: So far, I haven't had to add a jar for a native interface, and I haven't created a cn1lib. I would probably start without trying to build the cn1lib. Just focus on creating the native interface. I believe that you just put the jar in the native folder (but continue deeper into the folder hierarchy to find the impl file) and the build server will manage it. You might need some include statement. I was hoping Shai would chime in on that part, but it might be discussed in the tutorial video or the developers guide.